# Receive JSON from a MS Message queue

Tags: c#, json, msmq

I have some trouble reading Json formatted message from a MS queue.

I am able to connect to the queue and read the first message but when trying to access the Body property the value is null.

Also when trying to read from the body stream I have also an error message saying the stream was not readable.

The queue is transactional but I don't think this is relevant here.

```cs
private readonly MessageQueue _queue;
private bool _listen;
private Func<object, bool> _messageHandler;

public Listener(string queuePath)
{
   _queue = new MessageQueue(queuePath);
}

public void Start(Func<object, bool> messageHandler)
{

   _listen = true;
   _queue.PeekCompleted += OnPeekCompleted;

   _messageHandler = messageHandler;

   StartListening();
}

private void StartListening()
{
   if (!_listen)
   {
      return;
   }

   try
   {
      _queue.BeginPeek();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred when peeking");
   }
}

private void OnPeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   _queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);
   var messageId = string.Empty;

   using (var transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction())
   {
     transaction.Begin();

     try
     {
        using (var message = _queue.Receive(transaction))
        {
           if (!_listen || message == null) 
           {
               return;
           }
           messageId = message.Id;

           if (ProcessMessage(message))
           {
               transaction.Commit();
           }
           else
           {
              transaction.Abort();

           }

        }
     } 
     catch (Exception exception)
     {
        transaction.Abort();
     }
  }

  StartListening();
}
```

Is there something special to do when sending json via MSMQ to retrieve message body ?

Many thanks

Comment: If there's a problem with your code, we need to see it in order to figure out whats wrong. Can't help much without it.

Comment: Can you send and receive other strings in the same way?

Comment: I haven't tried yet with XML